# How to hide soft keyboard without losing focus on searchview

Tags: android

Expand searchview when fragment is oppened , request focus on searchview but hide soft keyboard .

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.barcode,menu);
    MenuItem scan = menu.findItem(R.id.scanbarcode);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

       MenuItem scan = menu.findItem(R.id.scanbarcode);
       mBarcode = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) scan.getActionView();
       mBarcode.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.scanb));
       scan.expandActionView();
       mBarcode.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**write this in your activity in manifest   file**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

**and in your fragment rite this**

```
searchTditText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: try this getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: where to put this ?

Comment: in your activity

Answer (score 0):

Call this method to hide soft keyboard.

`public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
               }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```